# Integration by parts involving a special definition of a Dirac delta-distribution

Tags: integration, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

given a "definition" of a $\delta$-function as follows

$\int dz \, f(x,z) \, f^{-1} (y,z) = \delta (x-y)$ ,

I would like to know how to apply knowledge over this to solve an integral like

$\int dz \, \omega(x,y,z) \, f(x,z) \, f^{-1} (y,z)$  .

Integration by parts comes to mind but I am not really sure if this can be done by intpreting $f(x,z) \, f^{-1} (y,z)$ as a derivative of a delta function because of the way it works e.g. here: [derivative-of-a-delta-function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38424/how-do-you-do-an-integral-involving-the-derivative-of-a-delta-function)

Anyways I am stuck at the following point, because something obviously goes wrong

$\omega (x,y,z) \, \delta(x-y) |_{-\infty}^{\infty} -\int dz \, \partial_z \omega(x,y,z) \delta (x-y)$

Any hints on the possibilty of solving this are much appreciated.

Comment: What do you feel goes wrong?

Comment: The terms in the last expression are the same, therefore I get 0 as a result.

Comment: The terms are not the same as I calculate them. Also I'm not sure what is meant by the inverse of a function of two variables. It's confusing unless it is a vector valued function, but I think not.

Comment: To bring the first equation into context: In a paper by Hedin he defines the inverse of a greens function as $\int d(3) G(1,3) G^{-1}(3,2) = \delta(1,2)$. The numbers denote a set of variables (space,time,spin) e.g. $1=\vec{r},t,\sigma$.